Hosting Uno UI in Web-style sdk application
Is it possible to host the Uno application in Web.Sdk-style project ?
Like embedded UI ?
All the samples I've seen advise to create Web Assembly project , haven't seen the sample with simple ASP Core..
Thanks

As far as I know, the answer is no. Uno Platform cannot be embedded.

You should visit Uno Platform's discord. It's very welcoming and you can find team members from the Uno Platform team and active users. ;)
https://discord.gg/XjsmQHdKfq
